# How to show different leading in AppBar according to different url?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to show different `leading` widget in `AppBar` according to different url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Widget widget;

  switch (url) {
    case "url_1":
      widget = Widget1();
      break;

    case "url_2":
      widget = Widget2();
      break;

    case "url_3":
      widget = Widget3();
      break;

    default:
      widget = DefaultWidget();
  }

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(leading: widget),
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for answers. Finally I did it by:
flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
      switch (url) {
        case 'http://a.com':
          setState(() {
            title = 'page1';
            leading = null;
          });
          break;   
        default:
          setState(() {
            leading =  new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                onPressed: (() {
                  ...
                }),
            );
          });
          break;
      }
    });

Comment: not at all. done

Answer (score 0):

CopsOnRoad answer is good but if you need to get the url from a build configuration check out https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors

Comment: thank any way，Maybe it will be useful in my next flutter app.